# google webfont beta feature text not working in opera

Tags: css, opera, google-webfonts

One of Google-webfonts really useful features to optimize the request size is the `text` parameter from the webfont api: [Optimizing your font requests (Beta)](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started#Optimizing_Requests)

The bad news are, that in Opera (at leaset v12.16 on Mac) the requested characters are not rendered at all – which makes the whole thing useless. Check this in whatever normal browser and Opera: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8KcrQ/)

Anybody knows why this happens and how to cure it other than using a [CSS browser hack](http://browserhacks.com/) – I don't really care for the fancy webfont, if it only shows some font at all…

Comment: Working fine in Opera 12.16 on Windows as well as the latest Opera Blink version. Could this be a Mac thing? Have you tested Safari/Chrome on Mac?

Comment: Tested Safari/Chrome/Firefox on Mac – everything works fine. Maybe I should just file a bug on [Operas site](https://bugs.opera.com/wizard/)…